# Create a dict from two existing dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, collections

I have two dicts that have sets as their values.

```
Dct1 = {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6, 7], 'c':[8, 9, 10], 'd':[11, 12, 13, 14]}
Dct2 = {'TypeZ':['a', 'b'], 'TypeX':['c', 'd']}
```

I would like to create another dict that:
1. iterates through the items of the values in Dct1
2. checks if the key of the item's value is an item in the values of Dct2
3. uses the key of dct2 as the key for the new dct and the corresponding items of the values in dict one as the set values for the new dict

```
Dct3 = {'TypeZ':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'TypeX':[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}
```

I also want to avoid having duplicates in the values of Dct3.

Here's the snippet of the code I'm currently struggling with (the other dicts have already been successfully built):

```
RateByType = {}

for key, item in RoRaDct.items():
    for i, j in TpRtDct.items():
        for x in item:
            for y in j:
                if key == y:
                    RateByType[i].add(item)
```

But it is producing a key error. I've tried using defaultdict(set) but get a TypeError: unhashable type: set. The latter is the method I used to build the first two dicts.

Comment: You said the values are sets, but your code describes them as lists (and you discuss de-duplication).  Are the values of type `set` or of type `list`?

Comment: You missing `'` after `TypeX` in the Dct2 declaration

Comment: Why does `Dct3['TypeX']` include `11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a set out of `Dct2`'s keys and then create a `defaultdict` for `Dct3`, looping over `Dct2`'s keys and their corresponding values:

```
import collections
Dct1 = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6,7],'c':[8,9,10],'d':[12,12,13,14]}
Dct2 = {'TypeZ':['a','b'],'TypeX':['c','d']}
s = set(Dct2)
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key in Dct2:
    for k in Dct2[key]:
        d[key].extend(Dct1[k])
```

Result:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'TypeX': [8, 9, 10, 12, 12, 13, 14],
 'TypeZ': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
```

Comment: Thanks again. It works great. Is there anyway to exclude certain items from being added to the values in dict 3? Say exclude = ('c','e') and inserting a conditional "if k not in exclude:" after for k in Dct2[key]?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dct3 = {k: set.union(*map(lambda x: set(Dct1.get(x, [])), v)) for k, v in Dct2.items()}
```

For each key, value pair in `Dct2` we map the key to the union of the sets that are mapped to by the member elements of the value that are keys in `Dct1`.

EDIT: explanation

```
{k: v for k, v in Dct2.items()}
```

is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), that recreates `Dct2`.

```
set.union(*map(lambda x: set(Dct1.get(x, [])), v))
```

Is what we're using to build the set, but lets look at it from the inside out.

```
Dct1.get(x, [])
```

tries to access `Dct1[x]` and returns it.  If the dict has no key `x`, it returns an empty list `[]`

```
set(Dct1.get(x, []))
```

takes the result of `Dct1.get` above and converts it to a set.

```
lambda x: set(Dct1.get(x, []))
```

defines an anonymous function (i.e. it doesn't have a name).  that function just takes an input `x` and uses it to evaluate the expression `set(Dct1.get(x, []))`

```
map(lambda x: set(Dct1.get(x, [])), v)
```

`map` is a function that takes another function (in this case our lambda function) and an iterable (like a list) and then makes an iterable that applies that function to every element of the input iterable.

```
*map(lambda x: set(Dct1.get(x, [])), v)
```

The `*` operator in this context is used to unpack iterables.  So it takes an iterable like `[1, 2, 3]` and turns `add(*[1, 2, 3])` into `add(1, 2, 3)`

```
 set.union(*map(lambda x: set(Dct1.get(x, [])), v))
```

`set.union` is a function that takes multiple sets and computes their union, basically adding them all together.

Comment: I'm impressed by this answer but I have to concede that it's over my head. Not to say it's any less correct. Thank you.

Comment: @ShaunO if you'd like I can do a more verbose writeup to explain what's going on here.  I'm using some functional programming tools here, which can  be very powerful once you wrap your head around them.

Comment: I'd love to be able to wrap my head around it. If you really don't mind I'd be totally into learning more about the logic behind it.